# Why do I feel nauseous at the sight of blood, despite not being afraid of it?

Tags: human-biology, human-physiology, hematology

Every time I ask google this question, all it spits at me is info on blood phobias ^-^; basically, I've always been hugely interested in morbid stuff, but I noticed that I always feel sick when interacting with any sort of gore IRL - when I volunteered at a hospital to keep patients company, I had trouble staying calm around patients who had been in accidents when they were getting their bandages changes, or around patients who've had surgery when they drained their tubes. Yesterday in Anatomy we dissected a pig's heart, and I was super excited until we finally got them & I felt sick seeing it! I'm just confused because mentally I'm fine & don't mind being around that stuff, but physically I feel ill & its pretty annoying tbh :/

If it helps explain it at all, I do have issues with vasovagal syncope & tend to faint when getting blood drawn & being in a very warm, humid place, & I kinda have the same feeling with it? I'm not afraid of needles or heat, but I feel sick in those situations & end up fainting

Comment: Your last paragraph is helpful. A vasovagal response is not fear. Anecdotally, one of my medical school classmates struggled with this but was able to overcome the problem over time (by continuing to expose himself to the stimulus). Dissecting a human cadaver helped.  Posting this as a comment as it is anecdotal and I have no references at hand to back it up.

Comment: I usually experienced this as well in biology classes. I'm not particularly afraid of needles or anything. But in classes where we were talking about the internal body or blood (or similar topics), I would often get very dizzy--despite me finding it interesting!